# Google Analytics crushing with null exception with error com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(Unknown Source)

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am trying to use google analytics and I am obtaining a null value as exception, so I am blocked with difficulties to continue as I am not able to continue... I will try to describe the problem step by step.

1) My application class (Application) has got the following method in for getting a tracker:

```
public synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
    if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {
      GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
      Tracker t =  analytics.newTracker(ApplicationData.ANALYTICS_ID);
      mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

    }
    return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
  }
```

2) I run in my application a service in the background. In this service I have this error capturing:

```
    try {
              this.mymethod();
          } catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e(ApplicationData.APP_TAG, TAG + ":Error at first actions running " + e.getMessage());
          }
```

3) Within the class mymethod I perform several actions... up to a point where I am calling the getTracker methods. Within mymethod this is the part where I am getting the error:

```
    Application app = Application .getInstance();
    Tracker t = app.getTracker(
            TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
    // Build and send an Event.
    t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
        .setCategory(ApplicationData.ANALYTICS_EVENT_SYNC)
        .setAction(action)
        .setLabel(label)
        .build());
```

Ok so here is the problem, when I call the method "getTracker", I have an exception rose. However the value obtained is "null" and there is not error message from the exception.

As a summary:

- I call the method "this.mymethod()" from 2)
- mymethod() contains the code 3).
- The code 3) gets an instance from application described in 1).
- I received an exception "e", from the try/catch in 2)

The exception I received is captured in this error message:

```
              Log.e(ApplicationData.APP_TAG, TAG + ":Error at first actions running " + e.getMessage());
```

I am getting this message:

```
  ....:Error at first actions running null
```

Doing some debugging I have discovered that the application fails here without any exception appart from the null value:

```
      GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
```

Does somebody has any idea what's happening? I correct the way I am calling the application. There is absolutely no information I can use.

**EDIT**

Thanks to @djabi I am able to provide further data for the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException  
android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:114)   
com.google.android.gms.analytics.x.<init>(Unknown   Source)
com.google.android.gms.analytics.x.A(Unknown    Source)
com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics.<init>(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(Unknown    Source)
myapp.Application.getTracker(Application.java:231)  
myapp.sendEvent(GenericSync.java:81)    
myapp(Check.java:72)    
myapp.firstActions(UpdatingService.java:199)    
myapp.onHandleIntent(UpdatingService.java:144)  
android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)   
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)    
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Where:

myapp.Application.getTracker   at Application.java:231 is:

```
 GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
```

myapp.sendEvent at GenericSync.java:81 is:

```
Tracker t = app.getTracker(
        TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
```

myapp at Check.java:72 is:

```
 this.mymethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

Trebia, it looks like your application is not initialized yet at the time you are trying to access GoogleAnalytics. The context you provided to GoogleAnalayitcs.getSingleton() returns null when getApplicationContext() is called. Are you trying to initialize GoogleAnalytics from the Application constructor or a static initializer? If that is the case try moving the call to GoogleAnalytics.getSingleton(context) inside the Application.onCreate() method. If you have not done so yet you will need to provide custom application class extending Android Application class and update your application manifest "name" attribute with your app full class name.

Application.onCreate is guaranteed to be called on the main thread after the Application is initialized and before any other Android objects are created (Google Analytics will not be happy when initialized from a worker thread).

Comment: I will try to answer your questions one by one :). Thanks for your time. There is no null pointer I have an exception "e" which is null. The null pointer is the exception, I don't have the typical java lang. In other parts of the code, the context is used to read an sqlite database, so it is not null. In terms of order I call the method in 2), which calls the method 3), which calls the activity application. I will modify my description to give more clarity.

Comment: The "e" exception is not null, only the message. Can you please call Log.e() with the exception as separate parameter:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html#e(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Throwable)
It will print the call stack and extra information.

Comment: Thanks!!! I updated the error track which now is clearer. I google the error and I did not find the error